# ExpressionEngine no_results not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, expressionengine

Hi I have the following code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <h3>Top 10 most popular</h3>
        <ul>
            {exp:channel:entries channel="faqs" dynamic="no" limit="10"}
                <li><a href="{url_title_path='help'}">{title}</a></li>
            {/exp:channel:entries} 
        </ul>

        <h3>Answer to selected question</h3>
        {exp:channel:entries channel="faqs" dynamic="yes" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
             {if no_results} 
                <p>Click a question above to see the answer here</p>
             {/if}
            {answer}
        {/exp:channel:entries} 
    </div>    
</div>
```

So as you can see I am looping through faqs twice. The first set it to get all of the questions and then if a user clicks on a question thats when the second loop should kick in to show them the answer. This works fine apart from the no results statement in the second loop doesn't work. It just never gets output. Anyone know why?

Comment: Are both loops displayed on the same page, with no other entry_id or url_title segments?

Comment: Are you by chance using Stash and the "template partials" approach in your templates? `no_results` does not work as expected in that circumstance. If that is the case for you then [this thread](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/3081) may help.

Comment: Yeah I am using stash. Sorry I didn't realise this was the problem otherwise I would have mentioned it

Comment: I don't know for sure that it is now that I look at it. I've got a few sites using template partials approach and the `no_results` tag seems to be working just fine to redirect to the 404 template, though I could have sworn I'd seen it _not_ working in the past. What version of Stash are you using?

Comment: The thread I linked to in my comment above is pretty outdated. I found that getting `no_results` working with Stash was just a matter of using the beta version and the `no_results_prefix` (see my answer below).

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to add

```
require_entry="yes"
```

to your second loop in order for the no results to work.

See the docs here http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#require-entry

Comment: That's still not working. I've updated the code in the question to reflect

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned in the comments that you are using Stash, this following should get `no_results` working as expected. I've just tested this and it works for me.

Download the beta version of Stash here https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev (currently v2.3.5).

See the documentation on [no_results_prefix](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/tree/dev#no_results_prefix--string) on the GitHub page.

You did not show the surrounding Stash tag that wraps your template code, but assuming it is a `stash:set` tag, update your template something like this:

```
{exp:stash:set name="page_content" no_results_prefix="stash"}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">

            [...]

            <h3>Answer to selected question</h3>
            {exp:channel:entries channel="faqs" dynamic="yes" require_entry="yes" limit="1"}
                {!-- note prefix, which was defined in outer stash:set tag --}
                {if stash:no_results} 
                    <p>Click a question above to see the answer here</p>
                {/if}
                {answer}
            {/exp:channel:entries} 
        </div>    
    </div>
{/exp:stash:set}
```

Answer (score 0):

I reported this to EllisLab as a bug. It is definitely not working as it should. https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/21106